# Can someone help me with determining the width/height of the Samsung a10

Tags: web, responsive-design, mobile-website

I am trying to figure-out the viewport for the phone Samsung a10 for responsive design of my website. Now it mentions a resolution of 720 x 1520 pixels, which is defiantly to big to be a phone size. It mentions a pxiel density of 271ppi. So, my question is how do I work out the actual viewport of the Samsugn a10

Here is a link to the specifications: https://www.gizmochina.com/product/samsung-galaxy-a10s/

I tried looking up answer elating to this, but don't quite understand the information.

Answer (score 0):

Use the width in your script
Not viewport width.

That way you can avoid this issue.